# One user cannot access website from anywhere in the network

Tags: permissions, iis-7.5

This is really weird but here goes:

I have a domain user who just recently is unable to access a particular website on our intranet no matter what computer he logs on from.

He can access other sites on the same server as well. Just not this particular one.

The security permissions on the website (everyone full control) have not changed.

He is the only user reporting the issue and he was able to connect a couple of weeks ago.

When he access the website in question his browser just spins and spins (whether he uses IE or Chrome). I do NOT see the requests even making it in to the w3svc logs.

Does anyone have any idea as to what could be going on?

**UPDATE:**

I made the user a local admin on the web server in question. I then ran Network Monitor 3.4 with me logged in, started a capture and then opened the site. It opened no problem for me.

I then logged off, logged in as the user in question and ran Network Monitor again, following the same steps I did previously.

I washed and repeated the above once more for myself and the user.

I am not a network expert but I noticed that the captures looked totally different:

When he is logged in it shows the IIS worker process in the process list and only shows LDAP entries between the local machine and one of the three configured gateways.

When I am logged in do NOT see the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe) and my general entries look much much different.

Is there something to check in LDAP \ DNS that could be preventing the user from connecting? He's tried connecting via IP too and no dice.

Comment: What do your logs and packet captures say?

Comment: That's the problem. No trace. I am having him log onto the web server now and see what happens.

Comment: You've tried a packet capture and there are no packets from this user's machine?

Comment: I havent done packet capture just yet.

Comment: That would be a very simple way to get a better idea where the source of the problem is.

Comment: Updated my question to reflect what happened when I used netmon